# How to get response Entity with List?

Tags: json, hibernate, http, jakarta-ee

I have Object which has attribute: `List<Node> nodeChild;` 
When I return response: 
   `return new ResponseEntity<>(myObject, HttpStatus.OK);` 
In browser I get json with all attributes , but without list nodeChild inside myObject .

Entety:

```
@Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name="node")
public class Node implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id_node")
protected int id_node;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id_parent")
protected Node id_parent;

@Column(name="node_name")
protected String node_name;

@JsonBackReference
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "id_parent",cascade =     CascadeType.ALL)
protected List<Node> nodeChild;
```

This is what I got:

```
{"id_node":2,"id_parent":{"id_node":1,"id_parent":null,"node_name":null},"node_name":null}
```

In java when I try before return response ...  myObject.getNodeChild(); I got  the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to annotate `id_parent` with `@JsonBackReference`, and `nodeChild` list with `@JsonManagedReference`, as described [here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureBiDirReferences):

> @JsonManagedReference is the "forward" part of reference: one that
>   gets serialized normally, and handling of which triggers back-linkage
>   for the other reference. Annotated property can be a bean, array,
>   Collection (List, Set) or Map type, and it must be a bean property
>   (handled by a property of type serialized using BeanSerializer).
>
> @JsonBackReference is the "back" part of reference: it will be omitted
>   from serialization, and re-constructed during deserialization of
>   forward reference. Annotated property must be of bean type.

Comment: Yes, that's correct ! It's working.  Thank you! I Hvala ;)